# Price Set Total Amount not displaying and JS errors

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, contribution-page, price-sets

I have a Jooma 3.8.13 civicrm 5.5.1 install. I am using a price set on a membership contribution page, but the total amount is not displaying.
All works fine on test drive but on the live page no total amount is displayed at all, either initially or when any items from the price set are chosen.
Changing templates makes no difference, same issue on joomla default templates.
The price total calculation is working as when contribution is confirmed the next pages shows the correct amounts.
I know that the total amount is calculated using javascript. And I am seeing JS errors on browser console.
I did the usual - Directory path in CiviCRM/Resource URL/Cleanup CiviCRM Cache

Comment: From browser console:Empty string passed to getElementById(). js-c5f31-74822.js:7:24932

Comment: Do the browser console errors happen before you select a price, or after?  Also, it looks like you've got some JavaScript aggregation going on, combining all your JS into one file.  That's good for performance but bad for troubleshooting - are you able to turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CiviCRM Resource URL - long standing bug in Joomla version, still in civi 5.9.0.
Replace [civicrm.root] with absolute URL.